# Smart SQL group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL `table: names, location, volume`

- `Names are of type string`
- `Location are two fields of type float (lat and long)`
- `Volume of type int`

**I want to** run a SQL query which will **group all the locations in a certain range and sum all the volumes**.

For instance `group all the locations from 1.001 to 2 degrees lat and 1.001 to 2 degrees long into one with all their volumes summed from 2.001 to 3 degrees lat and long and so on.`

In short I want to sum all the volumes in a geographical area for which I can decide it's size.

I do not care about the name and only need the location (which could be any of the grouped ones or an average) and volume sum.

Here is a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example` (
  `name` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float NOT NULL,
  `lng` float NOT NULL,
  `volume` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `example` (`name`, `lat`, `lng`, `volume`) VALUES
("one", 1.005, 1.007, 2),
("two", 1.25, 1.907, 3),
("three", 2.065, 65.007, 2),
("four", 2.905, 65.1, 10),
("five", 12.3, 43.8, 5),
("six", 12.35, 43.2, 2);
```

For which the return query for an area of size one degree could be:

> 1.005, 1.007, 5
>
> 2.065, 65.007, 12
>
> 12.3, 43.8, 7

I'm working with JDBC, GWT (which I don't believe makes a difference) and MySQL.

Comment: can you provide with table structure and sample data?

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are content with decimal points, then use `round()` or `truncate()`:

```
select truncate(latitude, 0)as lat0, truncate(longitude, 0) as long0, sum(vaolume)
from t
group by truncate(latitude, 0), truncate(longitude, 0)
```

A more general solution defines two variables for the precision:

```
set @LatPrecision = 0.25, @LatPrecision = 0.25

select floor(latitude/@LatPrecision)*@LatPrecision,
       floor(longitude/@LongPrecision)*@LongPrecision,
       sum(value)
from t
group by floor(latitude/@LatPrecision),
         floor(longitude/@LongPrecision)*@LongPrecision
```

Comment: perhaps float(10,6) a better datatype for `latitude and degree`?

Comment: @bonCodigo Can you please explain why?

Comment: @me1982 . . . The reason is to avoid rounding errors.  A latitude might look like 2.0000000, but it is really stored as 1.999999999999999999999997 (or something like that).  Giving a precision in the declaration makes the results more "you get what you see".

Answer (score 0):

Convert latitude from float to int and then group by converted value. When the float is converted, say from 2.1 or 2.7, i think it becomes 2. Hence all values between 2.000 to 2.999 will have the same converted value of 2. I am from SQL server, hence the SQL will be base d on sql server

```
select cast(l1.latitude as int), cast(l2.latitude as int) sum(v.volume)
from location l1
join location l2 on cast(l1.latitude as int) = cast(l2.longitude as int)
join volume v
group by cast(latitude as int), cast(l2.latitude as int)
```

Comment: This is nice but not enough. It does not allow to change the size of an area.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am super late to send this answer:

- [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c12ef/22)

Code:

```
select round(x.lat,4), round(x.lng,4),
sum(x.volume)
from (
select 
case when lat >= 1.00 and lng <2
then 'loc1' end loc1, 
case when lat >= 2.00 and lng <3
then 'loc2' end loc2,
case when lat >= 3.00 and lng >10
then 'loc3' end loc3,
  lat, lng,
volume
from example) as x
group by x.loc1, x.loc2, x.loc3
order by x.lat, x.lng asc
;
```

Results:

```
ROUND(X.LAT,4)  ROUND(X.LNG,4)  SUM(X.VOLUME)
1.005           1.007       5
2.065           65.007      12
12.3            43.8        7
```

Comment: @me1982 Please take a look at this sqlfiddle demo, the code and comment :) here you can change the size of `lat` , `lng` so to adjust your own grouping.

Comment: Thank you but this is definitely not generic, and entering all the possible lats and longs is not an option.